# PHP :: Stumped on how to reference specific row in a mysql select array...?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am just not making a connection here, and im not getting search results that are helping me enlighten myself.

I am pulling data from mysql into an array. But I am tottaly missing how I reference a specific row later.

```
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=FermentorDB', $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



$chamberstate = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM ChamberState' . $conn->quote($mac));


foreach($chamberstate as $row) {
    $chamber = $row['Chamber'];
    $schedule = $row['Schedule'];
    $runningnow = $row['RunningNow'];
    $temp = $row['ChangingTemp'];
    $array = array($chamber,$schedule,$runningnow,$temp); 


    }


} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
```

Ok, so all the data is in the array. But how do I , say, print the $schedule where $chamber == 1 ?

I feel so dumb for not getting this.....

Comment: It's not really a mysql question, just an array question. Try echo '<pre>'; var_dump($array);echo '</pre>'; that will show you the array then you can access keys by $array[0] $array[1] etc

Comment: SELECT * FROM ChamberState where schedule = 1

Comment: Thanks for the reply Coz. My goal is to only create one transaction with the sql database. Changing the sql statement to include WHERE will still require many sql transactions. 

The first option of using the row number to access the data is useful, but the rows can not be ordered in the appropriate fashion for the row number to be predictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with your original code but the `$array` variable was being overwritten each time through the loop. If you need to access the values throughout your page ou should be able to do so with an approach like this.

```
<?php
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=FermentorDB', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $chamberstate = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM ChamberState' . $conn->quote($mac));

        /* Populate this array for later use */
        $chambers=array();

        foreach( $chamberstate as $row ) {
            $chamber = $row['Chamber'];
            $schedule = $row['Schedule'];
            $runningnow = $row['RunningNow'];
            $temp = $row['ChangingTemp'];

            /* This will overwrite any values in the $array variable with each iteration through the loop */
            /*
                $array = array( $chamber, $schedule, $runningnow, $temp ); 
            */

            $chambers[]=array( 'chamber'=>$chamber, 'schedule'=>$schedule, 'running'=>$runningnow, 'temp'=>$temp );
        }


        /* later, when you need to access the various values, you can reference via the index */
        echo $chambers[ 1 ]['chamber'];

        /* or */
        echo $chambers[ 23 ]['schedule'];


    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton for the quick response and well documented code!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=FermentorDB', $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$chamberstate = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM ChamberState' . $conn->quote($mac));
$caray = array();
foreach($chamberstate as $row) {
    $caray[$row['Chamber']]['Chamber'] = $row['Chamber'];
    $caray[$row['Chamber']]['Schedule'] = $row['Schedule'];
    $caray[$row['Chamber']]['RunningNow'] = $row['RunningNow'];
    $caray[$row['Chamber']]['ChangingTemp'] = $row['ChangingTemp'];

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
print_r($carray['1']);
?>
```